# Проверка версии приложения через текстовой файл на хостинге

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Не получается определить ошибку, код ругается на то, что cлишком кроткая или длинная часть строки версии. Но на деле это не так, в файле содержится текст 1.0.0.0 (без пробелов и прочего). Атрибут `AssemblyInfo.cs` содержит значения по умолчанию:

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

`[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код определения версии, через ссылку ведущую к файлу `version.txt`

```
    private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Version currentVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        WebClient http = new WebClient();
        Version latestVersion = new Version(http.DownloadString("http://sub.domain.com/version.txt"));
        if (latestVersion > currentVersion)
        {
            // Доступна новая версия
            MessageBox.Show("Доступна новая версия");
        }
        else
        {
            // Новых версий не обнаружено
            MessageBox.Show("Новой версии пока нет");
        }
    }
```

Comment: А формат получаемого latestVersion какой?

Comment: Должен быть таким N.N.N.N

Comment: А на деле latestVersion что содержит? Проверь)

Comment: Подскажите где проверить? (извиняюсь за задержку, пропал инэт)

Comment: вот это `var v = new Version("1.0.0.0");` работает прекрасно, что означает, что вы передаете туда что то другое.

Comment: Проблема в строчке `(http.DownloadString("http://sub.domain.com/version.txt"))` не ясно какая причина...

Comment: Так вы не пишете что эта строчка возвращает, а без этого знания вам никто не поможет

Comment: Как получить значения строчки?

Comment: Воспользоваться отладкой

Comment: Проблема, в самом хостинге, некоторые хостинги подсовывают кучу лишнего кода и скриптов, прежде чем открыть содержимое файла. В моем случае вместо `1.0.0.0` был `html` код и прочий `js` код.